# AD Password expiry notification from technet gallery

Tags: powershell

I try edit powershell password email notification from
- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Password-Expiry-Email-177c3e27
or
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2015/05/04/how-to-setup-a-password-expiration-notification-email-solution/

I like to send log in html file and I try add 2 new column $sent, $expireson. 
I add 2 columns to get-aduser query but results in this columns is bad.
I don't know what can I do to make the code work properly.

My code below:

```
$smtpServer="mail.company.com"
$expireindays = 52
$from = "Company Administrator <support@mycompany.com>"
$logging = "Enabled" # Set to Disabled to Disable Logging
$logFile = "C:\scripts\test.html" # ie. c:\mylog.csv
$testing = "Enabled" # Set to Disabled to Email Users
$testRecipient = "testuser@company.com"
$filecontent = (Get-Content $logfile | Out-String)

# System Settings
$textEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$date = Get-Date -format ddMMyyyy
# End System Settings

# Get Users From AD who are Enabled, Passwords Expire and are Not Currently Expired
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = get-aduser -filter * -properties Name, ``PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress |
where ($_.Enabled -eq "True") | where {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false} | where {$_.passwordexpired -eq $false} |
@{N="column1";E= {$expireson}}, @{N="column1";E= {$sent}} |
Convertto-html | out-file $logfile

# Process Each User for Password Expiry
foreach ($user in $users)
{
$Name = $user.Name
$emailaddress = $user.emailaddress
$passwordSetDate = $user.PasswordLastSet
$PasswordPol = (Get-AduserResultantPasswordPolicy $user)
$sent = "" # Reset Sent Flag
# Check for Fine Grained Password
if (($PasswordPol) -ne $null)
{
    $maxPasswordAge = ($PasswordPol).MaxPasswordAge
}
else
{
    # No FGP set to Domain Default
    $maxPasswordAge = $DefaultmaxPasswordAge
}


$expireson = $passwordsetdate + $maxPasswordAge
$today = (get-date)
$daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days

# Set Greeting based on Number of Days to Expiry.

 # Check Number of Days to Expiry
$messageDays = $daystoexpire

if (($messageDays) -gt "1")
{
    $messageDays = "in " + "$daystoexpire" + " days."
}
else
{
    $messageDays = "today."
}

# Email Subject Set Here
$subject="Your password will expire $messageDays"

# Email Body Set Here, Note You can use HTML, including Images.
$body ="
Dear $name,
<p> Your Password will expire $messageDays<br>
To change your password on a PC press CTRL ALT Delete and choose Change Password <br>
<p>Thanks, <br> 
</P>"

# If Testing Is Enabled - Email Administrator
if (($testing) -eq "Enabled")
{
    $emailaddress = $testRecipient
} # End Testing

# If a user has no email address listed
if (($emailaddress) -eq $null)
{
    $emailaddress = $testRecipient    
}# End No Valid Email

# Send Email Message
if (($daystoexpire -ge "0") -and ($daystoexpire -lt $expireindays))
{
    $sent = "Yes"
    # If Logging is Enabled Log Details
    if (($logging) -eq "Enabled")
    {
        Add-Content $logfile "$date,$Name,$emailaddress,$daystoExpire,$expireson,$sent" 
    }
    # Send Email Message
    #Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -from $from -to $emailaddress -subject $subject -body $body -bodyasHTML -priority High -Encoding $textEncoding   

} # End Send Message
else # Log Non Expiring Password
{
    $sent = "No"
    # If Logging is Enabled Log Details
    if (($logging) -eq "Enabled")
    {
        Add-Content $logfile "$date,$Name,$emailaddress,$daystoExpire,$expireson,$sent" 
    }        
}

} # End User Processing

#Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -from $from -to $emailaddress -subject $subject -body $body -bodyasHTML -priority High -Encoding $textEncoding

# End
```

Comment: Or i can make Log file with csv file but how can i make csv file with delimiter ";". However i dont know where i can add Export-Csv -Path c:\temp.csv -Delimiter ";" in my code.

Comment: Can i make some loop for $expireson variable?

Answer (score 0):

I fix my issue converting CSV to HTML and add some CSS. Now i have log in html table sending it to email.

```
$info = Import-Csv $logFile | ConvertTo-Html -head $style
$mailBody =
" 
$info
" 

Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -from $from -to $emailaddress -subject test -body $mailBody -bodyasHTML -priority High -Encoding $textEncoding
```